# Is it possible to install website made in php fox on localhost?

Tags: phpfox

I have website made in php_fox framework and my client want some changes on website but he don't want that changes on his server directly so firstly i have install that website on my localhost. so is it possible to install that website on localhost??? because right now i am getting 505 internal server error :(

Thanks,
Ruchita

Comment: yes you can install phpfox at local

Comment: please remove .htaccess file and make changes in include/setting/server.sett.php

$_CONF['core.url_rewrite'] = '2';

Answer (score 0):

yes, you have just to activate **rewrite_module** in apache from apache module (wamp)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your *`server.sett.php (\include\setting)`*

```
search $_CONF['core.url_rewrite']
```

value of this variable should be 2 at *localhost*

```
$_CONF['core.url_rewrite'] = '2';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `server.sett.php (\include\setting)`

1. change the following `$_CONF['core.host'] = 'localhost';`
2. edit this `$_CONF['core.folder'] = '/';` to `$_CONF['core.folder'] = '/<your_phpfox_dir>/';`
3. and edit `$_CONF['core.url_rewrite'] = '2';`
4. Additionally configure database settings
5. Delete everything inside `\file\cache`

Now run the phpfox instance in your localhost.